# WordPress page redirection automatic tout homepage

Tags: wordpress

I created a category in WordPress and I gave to this category the url of my blog page. It gave me a 404 error so i deleted the category. The problem is that now my blog page redirect to my homepage.
I don't know how to start . Any idea of what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by ensuring the blog page is different from the homepage in dashboard->settings->reading

Comment: I checked and Blog is different that home page

Comment: "By default, WordPress sets your site’s home page to display your latest blog posts. This page is called the blog posts index. You can also set your blog posts to display on a separate static page. The template file home.php is used to render the blog posts index, whether it is being used as the front page or on separate static page. If home.php does not exist, WordPress will use index.php."  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

You can try renaming the home.php file, or use another theme to see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks and make note of the current setting since you need to temporarily change it. Select the Plain radio button and click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.

Once saved, click the previous pretty permalink option you had and click Save Changes one more time.

Your permalink settings have been reset and you can check your blog page. You shouldn’t see any more 404 errors. Please check the blog page in other browser to prevent also the cache.

Comment: It didn't work. Idon't have 404 erro, it directly redirect to homepage